# Looping in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Looping test occurrence based on the data count retrieved from the JDBC request and also as input data for the HTTP request

I have test scenario where i need to use the DB output as the input criteria for the HTTP request. Based on the DB output count( from the first request) i need to loop the HTTP request and it data accordingly

I tried the logical Loop Count by passing the count variable from run time as ${TEST_ID_#}, still its not working.

I tried the logical Loop Count by passing the count variable from run time as ${TEST_ID_#}, still its not working.

Debug Sampler Output
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the counter using Post Processor [either Regular Expression Extractor or JSON Extractor etc.]

Once you have extracted that count, now place a Loop controller as a parent of HTTP request.

For example. I am using User Defined Variable for loop Count:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Loop count value i am defining based on the database output from step 1 of the script. The challenge is value is not getting parsed on counter variable eg: ${Test_key-#}

Comment: What do you mean by not getting parsed? How are you extracting loop count, using which extractor? Which variable name are you using? Have you used Debug sampler for debugging?

Comment: from the debug sampler of the DB response i will getting the count of records(Based on the value only i need to iterate ) Eg : TEST_KEY_ID_#=100. So i tried using this variable in the loop counter ${TEST_KEY_ID_#} to iterate the HTTP  request 100 times, but its not going into the loop.

Comment: Can you attach image of each steps in question? Also add Debug Sampler screenshot?

Comment: I have included the screenshot above. I  am retrieving the count of rows and data  from the JDBC request.  Loop controller is set base on the row count, i want to substitute data <currentkey>from the JDBC request for the HTTP request in the  loop

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for using `${TEST_ID_#}` variable? If your [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) screenshot is full and correct you should be using `${KEY_ID_#}` instead.

Also it might be a better idea to use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) instead of the Loop Controller, the relevant configuration would be something like:

[image]

References:

- [How to Use ForEach Controller in JMeter](https://www.testingexcellence.com/jmeter-foreach-controller/)
- [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter/)